# how to update controller's viewModel data from another controller

Tags: angularjs

Here is my scenario. I have one controller responsible for generating portion of html, and there is another controller within the same page to display some more html. Is it possible to pass data from one controller to another one? Is there a concept such as subscribe and publish?

Controller One is responsible for dealing with inserting new data into database, and upon successful insert, I want to populate the list located within Controller Two (pushing newly added item into Controller Two vm list data).

Is described scenario possible with angularjs?

More details, here is what I have:
[image]

As you see, there is one page with two separate views and controllers.

For generating View 1, I take advantage of angular directive:

```html
<add-new-task-section category-id="{{vm.categoryId}}"></add-new-task-section>
```

I have created service for View 1, so it will update View 2 list:

```js
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular.module("app-categories")
    .service('addingNewTaskService', function () {

        return {
            pushNewTask: function (data) {
                alert("UI to be updated for category: " + data.categoryId);
            }
        }

    });
})();
```

And here is how I call the working service from within View 1:

```js
        $scope.saveNewTask = function () {

            vm.newTask.categoryId = $scope.categoryId;

            addingNewTaskService.pushNewTask(vm.newTask);
```

It all works fine, I am successfully able to call the alert within the service, but how to push the vm of View 1 (data object of the service) into View 2 vm list?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope#scope-events-propagation

Comment: Please share psuedo html

Comment: I have updated question by providing more details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there is a concept of subscriber and publisher in angularjs. I was able to resolve my issue by publishing from View 1 and subscribing on View 2. I have removed my custom service from the code in the question, and referenced '$rootScope' angular service in View 1. From there I was able to publish with:

```js
$rootScope.$broadcast('newTaskSent', vm.newTask);
```

and subscribe in the View 2 with:

```js
        //subscriber
        $scope.$on('newTaskSent', function (event, task) {            
            vm.tasks.push(task);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can do this by sharing data via a service.  https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services